# Android view turn off implicit state retaining for some view

Tags: java, android

I have **custom** `View` which is dynamically added multiple times in same activity.

Each of custom view instance has beside other stuff a `TextView` child.
The `TextView` has it's **ID** and it is same for each view instance.

For each custom view instance I set different `Text` for `TextView` when activity is created.
When I rotate the screen, the activity is recreated but now each `TextView` displays same `Text` (text is same as text of the last instance).

**This is because the save and restore of instance state saves some information automatically, but this information is obviously linked to IDs and in my case creates the problem.**

Is there a way to disable automatic state retaining for particular views?

Is there a property or setting or some workaround?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use [`View.setSaveEnabled (boolean enabled)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSaveEnabled%28boolean%29) method.

It's also possible to disable automatic state saving via `xml` using `saveEnabled` attribute `android:saveEnabled="false"`

Comment: In my case also helpful to prevent `RecyclerView` saving its `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` state on orientation change and crashing with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on restoring with wrong span count.

Comment: Also solves "IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class" on rotation when a nestedScrollView hast the same ID in phone layout and in tablet layout there is another layout type being used with the same id, don't know about the drawbacks yet though.

Comment: You can also use [View.setSaveFromParentEnabled(boolean enabled)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSaveFromParentEnabled(boolean)) to disable state saving of the entire view hierarchy, e.g. you can set it on your root element and disable saving altogether.

Answer (score 3):

if you need apply setSaveEnabled for all hierarchy:

```
    public static void SaveEnableViewAndChildren(this View view, bool val)
    {
        if (view == null)
            return;
        view.SaveEnabled = val;

        var viewGroup = view as ViewGroup;
        if (viewGroup == null)
            return;
        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.ChildCount; i++)
            SaveEnableViewAndChildren(viewGroup.GetChildAt(i), val);
    }
```