# How to save view inside ViewGroup in Android?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-orientation

I create a custom `LinearLayout` where I can add `TextView` whenever user click on a `Button` from `Activity`. I click on the button 5 times and five TextView added. But the problem is after rotating the activity, the added view is completely lost. How can I retain the `LinearLayout` state. Here is my `LinearLayout` code.

```
       AddNewView(String text){
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(text);
        addView(textView);  
        }
```

Comment: Have you seen this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527456/android-view-turn-off-implicit-state-retaining-for-some-view)?

Comment: @sept this will not work cause new `View`s are added programmatically. @androidcodehunter you might tray retaining instance of `Fragment`, `Activity` can't do this (but might be when set in manifest as "single..." in `launchMode`). other way for `Activity` only constrution is to saving instance state and recreating in `OnCreate`. but `Bundle` can carry primitives only, so you might save only numer ov `TextView`s with their text and when recreating add proper numer of `TextView`s inside `OnCreate`

Comment: @snachmsm after doing some research I think your solution is right but I don't know if anything better possible than this. Thanks.

Comment: Why adding textview you can use listview.